# What does the symbol $\forall$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What does the symbol $\forall$ mean?  I am sure this is an easy question, but it's not really conducive for googling because I don't know the name of the symbol.  If you can just give me the name or a link where I can read about it that will probably be more than sufficient.

**Context:**
In the coursera course *Introduction to Mathematical Thinking* 
by Dr. Keith Devlin I came across this sentence in the set supplement reading:

> If we have to prove that the sets $A$ and $B$ are equal, we usually split the proof into two parts: $(a)$ Show that every member of $A$ is a member of $B$.
>  $(b)$ Show that every member of $B$ is a member of $A$.
>   Taken together, $(a)$ and $(b)$ clearly imply $A = B$. (The proof of both $(a)$ and $(b)$ is usually of the ‘take an arbitrary element’ variety. To prove $(a)$, for instance, we must prove $(\forall x \in A)(x \in B)$; so we take an arbitrary element $x$ of $A$ and show that $x$ must be an element of $B$.)

Thanks!

Comment: it reads as "for all" or, equivalently, "for each", "for every"

Comment: It's called ["For all"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_all)

Comment: @Jonathan few seconds short ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Thanks so much for including the context of your question. It didn't end up being necessary here, but it often is very important, so it's good to get into the habit of providing it.

Comment: You might find this useful for other symbols as well: [List of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

Comment: @Mufasa good link thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "for all". Look up "universal quantifier" on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

It means "for all"/"for each"/"for every." For example, $$(\forall x\in A)(x\in B)$$ translates to "For all $x\in A,$ $x\in B,$" meaning every element of $A$ is an element of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

$\forall$ = "For all",  $\exists$ = "There exists", Any other questions?

Comment: Nope, that's wonderful thanks